Driving 555 IC with CD4017
I am using CD4017 and 555 IC. Every time I press the 'next' button, a signal is sent to the 555 by the CD4017, and the LED turns on for a while (theoretically). But there is a problem. Since I go from high to high without dead time when I press the button, the 555 does not perceive this as a different signal. That's why the 555's trigger remains active all the time. Is there any way to solve this? Do you see any problematic connections or redundant connections in the circuit?


Update: The problem was solved today. Thanks for all the replies. I will also examine the discarded circuits.

First, please update your question with a description of what you want the circuit to do.  If the goal is to have the LED on for 9 button presses and then ignore more presses until reset, then yes there is a better way.

The schematic is very hard to read.  A better way is to have all positive power rails upward, all GND connections downward, input stuff to the left and output stuff to the right.  Switch > 555 circuit > 4017 circuit > LED.  To remove clutter, replace the wandering VCC and GND nets with individual symbols at each connected component.  When the question is more clear, answers will follow.  Also, both chips need power supply decoupling.

It is also worth noting that the unused pins on the 555 should not be left floating, I suggest you research best practice.

What's the purpose of the circuit, and what are the design reasons it's done with 4017 and 555? If you simply want to keep a LED on for some period of time when you press a button, the 555 can do it by itself. If something else, the whole circuit could be redundant and problematic.

Circuit purpose: Basically, when I press the next button 9 times, it should send a signal to the 555 sequentially and the LED should flash with each signal. The reason I don't connect the LED directly to the CD4017 is because I don't want the LED to stay on all the time. Additionally, when the last output on CD4017 is reached, the circuit should not return to the beginning. However, when the reset button is pressed, it should return to q0. My only problem now is that I cannot create a time difference between CD4017 outputs.

What should I do to avoid leaving the pins of the 555 idle?

I just updated the image as the source of the problem. The LED should go off for a while instead of constantly burning during transitions.

leave reset high so that it does not reset

There is no 555 ic in your picture

This is similar but is automated and does not have a next button, reset, and uses 10 leds and not 1.

I think you don't fully understand the problem. I just want the LED in the image to turn off for a while during transitions.  Since I switch from high to high, the LED stays on all the time. Can I solve this with a capacitor etc? Also, the source you sent does not open.

q0-q1-q2-q3 is all connected to each other, which is why it stays on. how long do you want it to be off for? If you want to alternate starting at q0, then it would be q0-q2-q4-q6-q8

And, can you convert this to a simulation (TinkerCAD, Falstad, etc.) so that we can help you. Just using the pictures is not enough. Also, how can you say that there is a 555 timer used, if there is none in your picture, your previous picture was better.

Why do you want me to turn it into a simulation? I think the problem is clear. As for how long it should remain closed; I didn't calculate this exactly, but I guess it should be around 10 milliseconds at least. And as I said, the opposite is also suitable (on for 10 milliseconds). All I want is a time difference between exits. I can't do it in q0-q2-q4-q6-q8 style because the number of outputs is not enough and there will be buttons missed in between.

The reason is, is because I think it would make debugging it easier. I revise the simulation, and give you back what I think is the proper schematic you want. I am not saying that the problem is not clear. simulations are easier for me to look at rather than a still image and words.

If I understand your initial question and subsequent comments, what you're looking for is a circuit with 555 and 4017 that turns on an LED for some amount of time (then off) for 10 consecutive button presses, and then stops responding to the button. A second button is used to reset the whole system.
If that's the case, the solution below should work. Instead of OR'ing together 4017 outputs, just have the 555 generate the LED pulse directly (on time set by RC time constant). That pulse also goes to the 4017 which steps through 10 states. On the last state it disables the step switch.
Attaching a mechanical switch directly to a clock pin generally does not work - the mechanical switch bounce causes multiple clocks to IC. The 555 circuit is impervious to switch bounce (or rather, a bounce will just restart the relatively long one shot, no harm done).

Monostable circuit from Texas Instruments LM555 datasheet.

A timing diagram solves many communication problems. Reading your question and your comments (which should be added to your question) I think you've got this:
      _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   
CLK _| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_
      ___
  0 _|   |___________________________________
          ___
  1 _____|   |_______________________________
              ___
  2 _________|   |___________________________

Figure 1.
but you want this:
      _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   
CLK _| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_
      _
  0 _| |_____________________________________
          _
  1 _____| |_________________________________
              _
  2 _________| |_____________________________

Figure 2.
The easiest way to achieve this is - assuming your clock has a 50% duty-cycle (your question is vague on this) is to AND the LED with the clock.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 3.
The clock will work as normal but the LED can only turn on when CLK is high.

Why does the 555 timer show 7555

Also how does one use circuitlab.

@SnappyRiffs the 7555 is a common CMOS variant of the 555.

Is there any harm in using 555 instead of 7555?

The 7555 is better. It has lower power consumption. From memory, the 555 can cause a glitch on the supply when switching so decoupling capacitors are required. Do a web search for a comparison between the two. You should get thousands of results.
